# to match rows in two files

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have two tab delimited files:

file A

```
chrM    150
chrM    5581
chr1    717485
chr1    719097
```

file B

```
chrM    150
chrX    5581
chr1    717485
chr2    719097
```

The rows that exist in both files should only be printed:

```
   chrM 150

    chr1    717485
```

Second question if I have multiple columns in both files, how can I match still the first two columns of both files and if it matches, then print the lines from first file.
Sample data

file A

```
150 .   T   C   7807.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=247;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=4.7038;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=51.13;MQ0=0;QD=31.61;VQSLOD=3.92;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,247:247:99:7836,727,0
chrM    195 .   C   T   5638.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=176;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=2.5193;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=42.23;MQ0=0;QD=32.04;VQSLOD=3.62;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,176:176:99:5667,517,0
chrM    199 rs72619362  T   C   5058.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=169;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.7887;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.55;MQ0=0;QD=29.93;VQSLOD=4.68;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,169:169:99:5087,472,0
chrM    204 rs3135032   T   C   4110.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=168;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.77;MQ0=0;QD=24.47;VQSLOD=2.90;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,168:168:99:4139,435,0
chrM    217 rs41531144  T   C   4589.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=147;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=42.78;MQ0=0;QD=31.22;VQSLOD=4.51;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,147:147:99:4618,418,0
```

file B

```
150 .   T   C   7807.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=247;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=4.7038;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=51.13;MQ0=0;QD=31.61;VQSLOD=3.92;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,247:247:99:7836,727,0
chrM    195 .   C   T   5638.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=176;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=2.5193;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=42.23;MQ0=0;QD=32.04;VQSLOD=3.62;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,176:176:99:5667,517,0
chrM    199 rs72619362  T   C   5058.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=169;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.7887;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.55;MQ0=0;QD=29.93;VQSLOD=4.68;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,169:169:99:5087,472,0
chrM    205 rs3135032   T   C   4110.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=168;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.77;MQ0=0;QD=24.47;VQSLOD=2.90;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,168:168:99:4139,435,0
chrM    214 rs41531144  T   C   4589.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=147;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.0000;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=42.78;MQ0=0;QD=31.22;VQSLOD=4.51;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,147:147:99:4618,418,0
```

Output

```
150 .   T   C   7807.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=247;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=4.7038;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=51.13;MQ0=0;QD=31.61;VQSLOD=3.92;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,247:247:99:7836,727,0
chrM    195 .   C   T   5638.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=176;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=2.5193;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=42.23;MQ0=0;QD=32.04;VQSLOD=3.62;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,176:176:99:5667,517,0
chrM    199 rs72619362  T   C   5058.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=169;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.7887;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.55;MQ0=0;QD=29.93;VQSLOD=4.68;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,169:169:99:5087,472,0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep -f` is the way... but was already indicated by Johnsyweb.

From `man grep`:

> **-f FILE**, --file=FILE
>
> Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero
>   patterns, and  therefore  matches  nothing. (-f is specified by
>   POSIX.)

With `awk` you can also do:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]; next} $0 in a' f1 f2
chrM    150
chr1    717485
```

---

### Update

If you have to match just first two columns, then you cannot use `grep` anymore (at least in an easy mode). This `awk` makes it (updated, [thanks Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682760/to-match-rows-in-two-files/25682819#comment40152878_25682819)!):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1,$2]; next} ($1,$2) in a' f2 f1
150 .   T   C   7807.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=247;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=4.7038;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=51.13;MQ0=0;QD=31.61;VQSLOD=3.92;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,247:247:99:7836,727,0
chrM    195 .   C   T   5638.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DP=176;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=2.5193;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=42.23;MQ0=0;QD=32.04;VQSLOD=3.62;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||) GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,176:176:99:5667,517,0
chrM    199 rs72619362  T   C   5058.77 PASS    AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;DB;DP=169;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HaplotypeScore=0.7887;MLEAC=2;MLEAF=1.00;MQ=39.55;MQ0=0;QD=29.93;VQSLOD=4.68;culprit=MQ;EFF=intergenic_region(MODIFIER||||||||)  GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  1/1:0,169:169:99:5087,472,0
```

Comment: One more question, if I have file B with multiple columns, then what edits should I make in the above command.

Comment: @Angelo mmm could you update your question with some sample data? So that it is more clear what exactly you mean and what is desired output. Thanks!

Comment: wrt the awk solution - just switch the file order and you don't need to store the whole of file1 in memory and explicitly write the print command, e.g. `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2];next} ($1,$2) in a' f2 f1`.

Answer (score 4):

You can read one of the files into `%s` hash, where keys are lines and loop over other using hash as a look up table,

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{local @ARGV=pop; @s{<>} = ()} print if exists $s{$_}' fileA fileB
```

**Switches**:

- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 3):

[grep](/questions/tagged/grep) one or more newline separated patterns from file (`-f`) `A` in `B`:

```
% grep -f A B   
chrM    150
chr1    717485
```